# What does "top half" mean in "There are only two seeded players left in the top half of the draw"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> There are only two seeded players left in the top half of the draw.

I only know 1st, 2nd, etc. half, when we are talking about matches. I believe that "draw" here means a set of matches. What does "the top half of the draw mean"?

Comment: "1st, 2nd, ***etc.*** half"? (@_@)

Answer (score 5):

The draw you're referring to is for a tournament elimination draw where players compete until one winner is crowned. In the image below, as you can see, there is a top half and a bottom half. Seeds are the top players in the tournament and have numbers designating their rank.

[image: Draw]

Comment: In particular, the "top half" (slots 1-8 in the diagram) produces one person who advances to the final, and the "bottom half" produces the other finalist.  So if only 2 seeded players are left in the top half, the implication is that one of them is likely to reach the final, regardless of how many rounds away the final is.  (This is a much more meaningful statement in the early rounds of a large tournament with more rounds; 2 seeded players out of 4 left is not a big deal, but 2 out of 32 left is surprising.)

Comment: generally in a seeded tournament the top seeded player would be in the top row of the bracket, and the 2nd seed player would be in the bottom row of the bracket, in some cases the they put the 2nd seed player in the top row of the lower half. The goal is to have the two best players meet in the finals, not in the first round.